# How to pass values from view to controller in grails

Tags: grails, button, view, controller, action

I need to pass the Id value to my controller to execute the action. Currently this is what I have in my controller.

```
    def StartServer() {
    amazonWebService.ec2.startInstances(new StartInstancesRequest([InstanceToStart]))
    redirect action: index()
    }
```

The `InstanceToStart` value will come from the view. In my view I have a table with the following columns, Id and button:

```
i-333dced <Button>
i-dhdhdhd <Button>
i-er32ws  <Button>
```

When I press the button I want the Id to pass and then execute my action. My button code is as follows:

```
  <g:link action="StartServer">
  <input type="button" value="Start Server" class="stopimg" id="startServer"/>
  </g:link>
```

Answer (score 4):

- [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/createLink.html)
- [remoteLink](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html)
- [remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html)

Use anyone from above according to your need. I bet you will also get samples/questions/answers here in SO related to the same requirement if you search.

Comment: I used the create link and did something like this, <a class="runimg" href="${createLink(controller: 'AmazonEc2Controller', action: 'start', id: i.Id)}">Start Server</a>, however it is directing me to the start action rather than executing the start action.

Comment: I didn't get that, "directing to action but not executing it". When it is directed to the action then action should be in control what and how to execute. Take a look at what is returned from the action. Whether anything is returned or is any kind of rendering/redirect done? Plus, you should use `AmazonEc2` as controller name instead of `AmazonEc2Controller`.