# Grails button not executing my action?

Tags: grails, button, action, execute

I have this button in my view page

```
<a class="runimg" href="${createLink(controller: 'Ec2Controller', action: 'Start', id: i.Id)}">&nbsp;Start&nbsp;</a>
```

It is suppose to take the id of the instance and then pass it to my action in the controller. However it is looking for the Start view page rather than executing my action in the Ec2Controller. Any suggestion?

My controller has this

```
    def Start() {
    amazonWebService.ec2.startInstances(new StartInstancesRequest([InstanceToStart]))
    redirect action: index()
}
```

Comment: Post the full controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @Sérgio said, unless your controller is named `Ec2ControllerController`, your controller name is wrong. It should just be `Ec2`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem indeed

Answer (score 0):

You called a method index in your redirect:

```
redirect action: index()
```

It should be

```
redirect action: 'index'
```

Comment: tried that before already, it keeps directing me to http://localhost:8080/ec2/amazonEc2Controller/startServer

Comment: I'm confused. Your link points to `Ec2Controller`, but this link you mentioned is going to amazonEc2. And the name of the action is startServer and not Start?

Comment: @TestUser I think you got your answer here which I mentioned as comments in your [related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678135/2051952) question.