# How do you display all actions from your controller as a link in a gsp file in Grails?

Tags: grails, gsp

Basically, what I am trying to do is display all my actions from a controller in a gsp file so that the user can look at his/her possible methods that she can do in my website and all of those methods (actions) are in one controller . Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678135/2051952) could help you achieve what you seek.

Comment: Thanks! That helped out a lot. Here is what I did if anyone is curious :)                                                               <g:link action="Action Name Here">Action Name Here too</g:link>

Comment: James answer also works. It already creates a list for you with all your actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import grails.web.Action

List<String> actions = YourControllerClassHere.methods.findAll({ it.getAnnotation(Action) })*.name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer James. I put that in one of my actions for my controller and I created a gsp file for that action and made a link to display each of those methods. It works and displays my actions but it also displays way more other stuff than my actions like hasErrors, getActionUri, jsonHeader, getServletContext, redirect, etc. Can you show me how to get to just get my actions that I declared in my controller? Thank you!

Comment: Nvm, if you look at dmahapatro link that actually helped me create my own links with the actions I want. Thank you though!

Comment: Are you sure you copied it exact? I didn't have that experience.

Comment: I just noticed that I did not include the import and therefore grails didn't recognize the word Action. I had to change it to something else because I thought I Had to put my own action there or something. But now that I included the import, it worked! Thanks James :)