# Use a controller from a gsp?

Tags: grails, gsp

This is my first time using grails and i have a PersonController.groovy and it has some methods inside

In my spring toolkit. I can autogenerate a view for that person controller. and it can use the peroson controllers's methods.

in my view folder, i have personController folder and then some .gsp inside (autogenerated)

My problem is that, how can i use the person controller methods with a different .gsp  I created outside the personController view subfolder the same way the autogenerated view uses it?

Can i use the autogenerated views as templates then i just render them to my own gsp. Is that possible?

Comment: I hope [this would help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678135/2051952) on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to render views that don't exist in the `grails-app/views/person` folder, assuming you have something like:

```
grails-app/views/shared/edit.gsp
grails-app/views/shared/_edit.gsp
```

you can do so like this:

```
render view: "/shared/edit"
render template: "/shared/edit
```